# How to override the DomainClass.list() in GORM (Grails)

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

People, I'm facing a problem with **grails GORM**, my Application is totally dependent of the `DomainClass.list()` method, it is in all of my create/edit GSPs, but now I need a particular behavior for listing objects. Being more specific I need to filter these lists (All of them) by one attribute.

The problem is I'm hoping not to change all the appearances of these methods calling, so is there a way to customize the behavior of the default `list()` method ? I need it to function just the way it does, but adding an ending filter.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have the exact same problem, I added a DELETED status to my users and I do not want to modify all the code to call a new method, I just want that list() to not return deleted users

Comment: @Eduard same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use hibernate filter plugin (see [here](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/07/13/grails-hibernate-filter-plugin-a-life-saver/)). This will allow you to filter all finder methods (including `list()`) based on a property:

```
static hibernateFilters = {
    enabledFilter(condition: 'deleted=0', default: true)
}
```

Comment: FYI: I tested the hibernate filter plugin and it doesn't seem to work with Grails 2.0. Also, it doesn't work with `get()` calls

Comment: I don't know if it works for me, my problem is kinda complex. The filtering is not directly on domain-classes attributes, it is in a complex relationship, and I do not find out in the plugin docs if it really solves the problem. But this plugin can solve a simpler problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [names queries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html)? You could always do something like this:

```
class DomainClass {
    // ... class members

    static namedQueries = {
        myList { params->
            // put your complicated logic here
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just replace your calls to `DomainClass.list()` with `DomainClass.myList.list()`.

Comment: Actually my problem is that I don't want to replace all these DomainClass.list() callings. I'm studying grails metaprogramming to check if it can solve my problem....

Comment: Is it possible to make the named queries default?