# Grails / GORM where clause for hasMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am trying to add a where clause to my hasMany relationship as I have rows that I archive with a boolean value and do not want those showing up.  I know this is possible with hibernate via a where clause in the mapping, but not sure how or if it can be one in Grails.

thanks,

John

Comment: you may want to look at hibernate filter plugins  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9431630/74057

Comment: Looked in to that, but it does not work with grails 2.0

Comment: Hibernate filter is pretty simple plugin. You can fix it for grails 2.0 by replacing Domain.get() with Domain.findById()